# Не подключается шаблон к странице Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На сайте использую четыре раздела с одним шаблоном (копии, надо же post_type менять для каждого раздела, имя шаблона тоже меняю). На двух страницах шаблон подключился, на двух других нет.

```
<?php 
    /*
    *  Template name: Статьи
    */
    get_header();

    $my_blog = get_posts([
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'post_type'   => 'stati',
    ]);
?>

<?get_template_part("components/templates/blog", null, $my_blog)?>
```

Вместо данного шаблона подключается файл `index.php`. Проверял в БД в таблице wp_postmeta, на всех четырёх страницах указан правильный путь до файла, значит файл они видят, но подключают почему-то только два. Подсказали прописать в `function.php` такое подключение

```
add_filter('template_include', 'template_custom_include');
function template_custom_include($template) {
    if (get_the_ID() == 219) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . 'templates/template-stati.php';
    } else {

    }

    return $template;
}
```

Но оно так же не сработало. На одной из страниц, где шаблон показывается, была проблема, которую я устранил путём пересоздания "Ярлыка URL". На этих двух страницах сколько бы я не пересоздавал их, не подключается. Не знаю важно это или нет, эти разделы мною созданные post_type, приложу ещё код их регистраций. Статьи не подключают шаблон, Акции подключили.

```
<? add_action('init', function(){
    register_post_type('stati', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Статьи'),
            'singular_name' => __('Статья'), 
            'add_new' => __('Добавить статью'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Добавление статьи'),
            'edit_item' => __('Редактирование статьи'),
            'new_item' => __('Новая статья'),
            'view_item' => __('Смотреть статью'),
            'search_items' => __('Искать статьи'),
            'not_found' => __('Не найдено'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __(''),
            'menu_name' => __('Статьи'),
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit-large',
        'supports' => ['title','editor','thumbnail'],
        'has_archive' => 'stati',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    ]);
    register_post_type('akcii', [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => __('Акции'),
            'singular_name' => __('Акция'), 
            'add_new' => __('Добавить акцию'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Добавление акции'),
            'edit_item' => __('Редактирование акции'),
            'new_item' => __('Новая акция'),
            'view_item' => __('Смотреть акцию'),
            'search_items' => __('Искать акцию'),
            'not_found' => __('Не найдено'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __(''),
            'menu_name' => __('Акции'),
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-awards',
        'supports' => ['title','editor','thumbnail'],
        'has_archive' => 'akcii',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чём проблема. Проблема была в том, что slug и post_type у меня имели одинаковые значения. В вопросе я упоминал, что на одной странице проблема решилась тем, что я свой slug сбросил до генерируемого. Тогда же я сделал тоже самое и на других страницах, но там это не помогло. Теперь я выяснил, что slug и post_type не могут быть одинаковыми. Я полагаю, что это может только для русских версий движка, потому как мой коллега делает сайт, он не переключал язык движка на русский, у него slug и post_type могут иметь одинаковые значения и все шаблоны подключаются без проблем. Я не знаю как это работает